# Retrieve Twitter Direct Message images in C# Angularjs

Tags: c#, arrays, image, image-processing, twitter

From twitter direct message we get the media URL as "https://ton.twitter.com/1.1/ton/data/dm/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Mk2sMKio.png"
so to retrieve that image or show the image on the application we need to OAuth request which gives me Unicode data of the image. With the help of this https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/7700/post/9-Get-Twitter-Direct-Message-Images-in-PHP-with-the-OAuth-API.html

So now how to convert the Unicode data to Image in C#?

```
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(media);
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

It converts to base64 as well but the image is not getting displayed shows an invalid image or blank. I had tried the same with different images

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
byte[] imageBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(media);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true);

return image;
```

Comment: Yes correct but i get the error as Paramater not valid 
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)

Comment: byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(media);
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    byte[] b1= Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
                    Image image;
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b1,0, b1.Length))
                    {
                       // var b2= new Bitmap(ms);
                        
                        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                        
                    }